# Cycle Stop Valve and well booster pump

Tags: water, water-pressure, water-tank, water-hammer

I've been thinking about installing a CSV (cycle stop valve) after my F&W 2 horsepower booster pump to maintain a constant PSI at the house and put a stop to the water hammer. Has anyone done this? How does the above ground booster pump behave to the CSVs imposed flow restriction? Amperage cut down to compensate?

Comment: I have added pressure regulators to supply lines to limit the pressure, I am not quite sure what a cycle stop valve is.

Comment: This worked great. Booster pump derates and uses less electricity when restricted. I highly suggest this route for anyone on a well.